# MFC/C++ Change width of a item via code

Tags: c++, mfc, listcontrol

So I have a dialog which contains two ListControls.

I want to make one ListControl only visible to some people.

Lets say I have ListCtrl1 and ListCtrl2 (ListCtrl2 only visible for some people):

- When you are allowed to see both, ListCtrl1 is on the left and
  ListCtrl2 is on the right.
- When you are only allowed to see ListCtrl1, it should fill the whole
  Window alone.

I need to do this in the code, because only there I can check who is allowed and who not.

Comment: And, your problem.. is? What's wrong with dynamical control showing/hiding/resizing? Or do you expect us to write the code for you, without you even trying?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius The Problem is that I cant find it anywhere how to do it... no I expect helpful answers and not such trash, that helps noone. Thank you

Comment: Well, you could read the documentation, of `ListCtrl`, to see the available methods, and think about which ones should you do the job you want. That's the way I was learning things, back in the day.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius thats what i did... sorry that I'm not as smart as you. I mean you could have given me an answer to help me, but instead of that you write useless comments. But hey I already got an answer from someone who actually knows the point of this site...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your dialog as usual with the resource editor with *both* list controls.

If you want to show only `ListCtrl1` then use 
[`ShowWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx) to hide `ListCtrl2` and [`MoveWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534(v=vs.85).aspx) to resize `ListCtrl1` so it covers the whole area.

You probably also need [`GetWindowRect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`ScreenToClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162952(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Worked perfectly